# download csv file from a non-public dropbox folder to R

Tags: r, download, dropbox

How can I download to R a csv from a non-public folder in dropbox?

The source_DropboxData function in the rempis package solved the problem before but it is no-longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

In rempis you should include additional data for non-public files as it is shown in the article 
https://www.r-bloggers.com/dropbox-r-data/

or maybe just download the file and use read.csv function or read.csv2 and import it.